# How to wrap list items on smaller screens neatly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unsure how to really approach this,

I have an inline list which works perfectly on larger screens:

```
ul.skillslist{
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul.skillslist li{
        display:inline;
        border: 1px solid black;
        list-style-position: inside;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        background-color: #4849a2;
    }
```

[image: What it looks like on larger screens]

When I see how it responds on smaller screens, this is what it looks like:

[image: How it looks on smaller screens]

How do I make it looks much nicer, on the small screens, with a gap between the wrap when it goes beyond the visible screen?

Comment: Plz provide the respective HTML too.

Comment: You can add a `line-height-setting` to make the (wrapped) line higher. Start with `line-height: 1.8` and if that's not enough, increase the value gradually.

Comment: @isherwood - this helped! thank you, the only issue I have now is there is no distance between the two lines of items. Say I wanted to have a distance of 3px, would adding a top padding work?

Comment: Sure. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

add a media tag to change CSS on a certain width if you don't want to change the current look

```css
ul.skillslist{
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul.skillslist li{
        display:inline;
        border: 1px solid black;
        list-style-position: inside;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        background-color: #4849a2;
    }
    
  @media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
  /*800px or less screen width*/
  ul.skillslist li{
        display:inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
        list-style-position: inside;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        margin: 1vh;
        background-color: #4849a2;
    }
  
  
  }
```

```html
<ul class="skillslist">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>

</ul>
```